# How to get Transparent android activity over the lockscreen?

Tags: android, xml, android-theme

I want my activity to show up on lockscreen(which is working fine). but i want to get that activity transparent..
I tried 2 methods both are not allowing my activity to show on lockscreen.

**Method 1**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

**Method 2**

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Both are not allowing to show the activity on lockscreen.
Is there any method you know?

Comment: activity to show up on lockscreen is working for u ?

Comment: UI of the activity,root layout u have to set background as transparent.

Comment: Hi. How did you solve this? Please update with an Answer

Answer (score -1):

Try setting following codes in your activity.I have not tried it, it may work.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Comment: i am already doing that but these works fine if i don't add a theme

Comment: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

Comment: have you set "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>"  in
AndroidManifest.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you defined windowIsFloating to be true. An activity won't show in front of a lockscreen if the width or height are modified, or if it is set to be floating.

You should set windowIsFloating to false, windowBackground to transparent and if you would still like the dialog-effect, create a dialogfragment, and show that in your onCreate of the activity. And of course, remove the ActionBar from the activity:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```